# JFreeChart: move column labels upper

Tags: jfreechart

[image]

As I showed in the picture, I want to move the column labels (values 434, 2562, ....) a little upper. Is there any way to configure that? 
MY initial problem was that due to the differences between columns, the labels on the last 2 columns are not visible anymore (they are actually 15 and 24 or stg like that). I dont know how to change that. 
Thank you

Comment: You might want to look at the `ItemLabelDemo*.java` examples, seen in the [JWS demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html), and `DrawStringDemo`, mentioned in the [guide](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html).

Comment: excuse me, i dont see ItemLabelDemo

Comment: They are under `Miscellaneous > Item Labels`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`BarRenderer3D.setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition%28int,%20org.jfree.chart.labels.ItemLabelPosition%29).

For example :

```
  DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
  dataset.addValue(51.0, "Series 1", "key1");
  dataset.addValue(44.3, "Series 1", "key2");

  // create the chart...
  JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("Demo","Category","Value",dataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,false,true,false);


  CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();

  CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
  domainAxis.setVisible(false);

  NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
  rangeAxis.setUpperMargin(0.15);

  BarRenderer3D renderer = (BarRenderer3D) plot.getRenderer();
  CategoryItemLabelGenerator generator = new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator();
  renderer.setSeriesItemLabelGenerator(0, generator);
  renderer.setSeriesItemLabelsVisible(0, true);
  renderer.setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition(0, new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12,TextAnchor.BASELINE_CENTER));
  renderer.setItemLabelAnchorOffset(10);
```

The result is :

[image: Bar chart 3D with labels above the bars]

Answer (score 1):

```
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();

BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();

renderer.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12, TextAnchor.TOP_CENTER,TextAnchor.HALF_ASCENT_CENTER,0D));
```

Comment: For two columns (e.g. team1,team2 or Completed,Incompleted) for X-axis value, change last line to `renderer.setSeriesPositiveItemLabelPosition(0,new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12, TextAnchor.BASELINE_CENTER,TextAnchor.HALF_ASCENT_CENTER,0D));`. Changes are method is changed and 1st argument is 0 for 1st column for 2nd pass 1 so on.. This worked for me.